# A fraction in lowest terms $\frac{a}{b}$, such that $a+b=1024$, can also be written $\frac2n+\frac1{n^2}$. What is $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A certain fraction when expressed in it's lowest terms $\frac{a}{b}$ can also be written in the form $\frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2}$ where $n$ is a positive integer. For example $\frac{7}{9} = \frac{2}{3} + \frac{1}{9}$. If you are told in addition that $a+b = 1024$ what is the value of $a?$

I have tried to guess and check. I know that $b$ must be equal to a square number, so I checked all of the square numbers and the partners up to $1024$, but I feel like there is an easier answer with algebra that I am not seeing.

Would anyone be able to explain to me?

Comment: As a first step , use the representation $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2n+1}{n^2}$ which is in lowest terms. Now using $a+b=1024$ and inserting $a=2n+1$ , $b=n^2$ gives you a quadratic equation in $n$. Take it from here.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I suggest you concentrate on @Peter's comment, which seems much simpler to me than the two answers posted so far.

Answer (score 1):

$a=1024-b$

Therefore,

$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{1024}{b} -1$$

If this can be written as $\frac{2}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}$ we get

$$\frac{1024}{b} = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 \tag{1}$$

Let $b=s^2$

From $(1)$ we get

$$ \left(\frac{32}{s}\right)^2 = \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^2$$

$$\frac{32}{s} = \pm \frac{1+n}{n}$$

There is no solution for the $-$ sign case. Only solution is $s=n=31$.

Therefore, $b = 31^2 = 961$

Answer (score 1):

This expands a little on Peter's comment on the question.

$$\frac{a}b = \frac{2}{n} + \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{2n}{n^2} + \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{2n+1}{n^2}$$

Any prime factor of the denominator $n^2$ would have to divide $n$, and therefore cannot divide $2n+1$. So this final expression must already be in lowest terms, and we get $a=2n+1$ and $b=n^2$.

Substituting this into $a+b=1024$ we get $2n+1+n^2 = 1024$. The left hand side is $n^2+2n+1$ which should look familiar, and the right hand side is $32^2$. You can solve this quadratic equation to get two solutions for $n$, a positive and a negative one (which we can discount since we only want positive ones).

Answer (score 0):

**hint**
$$1024=2^{10}$$
$$\frac ab=\frac 2n+\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$=(1+\frac 1n)^2-1$$
so
$$\frac ab +1=(1+\frac 1n)^2=\frac{a+b}{b}$$

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I am still confused. I am in year 9 and this is all very confusing for me. Could you please dumb it down a little bit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using divisibility and a bit algebra.

You know
$$\frac ab = \frac{2n+1}{n^2} \Leftrightarrow n^2 a = (2n+1)b$$

Now, $a+b = 2^{10}$ and $n^2 = (n+1)^2 - (2n+1)$. Hence,

$$(n+1)^2 a = (2n+1)2^{10}$$

Since $n+1$ and $2n+1$ are prime to each other, you now know that

$$(n+1)^2 | 2^{10} \text{ and } a = (2n+1)\frac{2^{10}}{(n+1)^2}$$

Using again $a+b = 2^{10}$ you get also
$$b = 2^{10}-a = n^2\frac{2^{10}}{(n+1)^2}$$

So, the minimal possible $a,b$ are those when

$$(n+1)^2 = 2^{10}\Rightarrow n=31 \Rightarrow a= 63, b= 961$$